# why I do not display signals in windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

Let's write a C# program of type "Windows Forms Application" to create a
application simulating the modulation and amplitude demodulation of signal transmission
Analog.
The carrier signal, the modulator signal, the modulated signal will be graphically displayed/
demodulated and the function of spectral density of signals.
I tried to color the picture boxes and they are displayed, but not their content.
My goal is to draw the 4 lines which I want to display in the 4 Picture boxes.
How can I modify this code to get the spec waveformsifice modulation and demodulation in amplitude of an analog signal?

```
My code:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using static System.Math;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
        Application.Run(new ModulationDemodulationExample());
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    }
}


public class ModulationDemodulationExample : Form
{
    // Declare controls and variables
    private const int SignalLength = 100;
    private PictureBox carrierSignalBox = new PictureBox();
    private PictureBox modulatorSignalBox = new PictureBox();
    private PictureBox modulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox();
    private PictureBox demodulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox();
    private double[] carrierSignal = new double[SignalLength];
    private double[] modulatorSignal = new double[SignalLength];
    private double[] modulatedSignal = new double[SignalLength];
    private double[] demodulatedSignal = new double[SignalLength];
    private double carrierFrequency = 2.0;
    private Bitmap carrierSignalBmp;
    private Bitmap modulatorSignalBmp;
    private Bitmap modulatedSignalBmp;
    private Bitmap demodulatedSignalBmp;

    public ModulationDemodulationExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // Initialize form and controls
        Text = "Modulation and Demodulation Simulator";
        Size = new Size(800, 600);
        PictureBox carrierSignalBox = new PictureBox()
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 10),
            Size = new Size(360, 180),
            Visible = true,
            Name = "Carrier Signal"
        };
        PictureBox modulatorSignalBox = new PictureBox()
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 200),
            Size = new Size(360, 180),
            Visible = true,
            Name = "Modulator Signal"
        };
        PictureBox modulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox()
        {
            Location = new Point(400, 10),
            Size = new Size(360, 180),
            Visible = true,
            Name = "Modulated Signal"
        };
        PictureBox demodulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox()
        {
            Location = new Point(400, 200),
            Size = new Size(360, 180),
            Visible = true,
            Name = "Demodulated Signal"
        };
        Controls.Add(carrierSignalBox);
        Controls.Add(modulatorSignalBox);
        Controls.Add(modulatedSignalBox);
        Controls.Add(demodulatedSignalBox);

        GenerateSignal();
        CreateBitmaps();
        DrawSignals();
    }

    private void GenerateSignal()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SignalLength; i++)
        {
            carrierSignal[i] = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * carrierFrequency * i);
            modulatorSignal[i] = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i);
            modulatedSignal[i] = carrierSignal[i] * modulatorSignal[i];
            demodulatedSignal[i] = modulatedSignal[i] * carrierSignal[i];
        }
    }

    private void CreateBitmaps()
    {
        carrierSignalBmp = new Bitmap(carrierSignalBox.Width, carrierSignalBox.Height);
        modulatorSignalBmp = new Bitmap(modulatorSignalBox.Width, modulatorSignalBox.Height);
        modulatedSignalBmp = new Bitmap(modulatedSignalBox.Width, modulatedSignalBox.Height);
        demodulatedSignalBmp = new Bitmap(demodulatedSignalBox.Width, demodulatedSignalBox.Height);
        //carrierSignalBox.Image = carrierSignalBmp;
        carrierSignalBox.DrawToBitmap(carrierSignalBmp, carrierSignalBox.ClientRectangle);
        modulatorSignalBox.Image = modulatorSignalBmp;
        modulatedSignalBox.Image = modulatedSignalBmp;
        demodulatedSignalBox.Image = demodulatedSignalBmp;
    }

    private void DrawSignals()
    {
        DrawSignal(carrierSignalBox, carrierSignal, Color.Blue);
        DrawSignal(modulatorSignalBox, modulatorSignal, Color.Red);
        DrawSignal(modulatedSignalBox, modulatedSignal, Color.Green);
        DrawSignal(demodulatedSignalBox, demodulatedSignal, Color.Black);
    }

    void DrawSignal(PictureBox pictureBox, double[] signal, Color color)
    {
        // Get the graphics object for the PictureBox
        var graphics = pictureBox.CreateGraphics();
        // Clear the PictureBox
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        // Set the pen color
        var pen = new Pen(color);
        // Scale the signal's values to the size of the PictureBox
        var yScale = (double)pictureBox.Height / 2.0;
        var xScale = (double)pictureBox.Width / (double)signal.Length;
        // Draw the signal
        for (int i = 0; i < signal.Length - 1; i++)

        {
            var x1 = (int)(i * xScale);
            var y1 = (int)(yScale + (signal[i] * yScale));
            var x2 = (int)((i + 1) * xScale);
            var y2 = (int)(yScale + (signal[i + 1] * yScale));
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

    }
}
```

I created the 4 signals but I can not display them in form ,I would have liked each signal to be displayed in the PictureBox.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what issues you're running into now. Do you see nothing at all? Blank `PictureBox` controls? Please edit this question with more information.

My first hunch is that `InitializeComponent` is not the right place to call your 3 methods. It should be done well after initialization, maybe in a handler of [Form.Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which aspect of this are you having trouble with? Creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which focuses on just that aspect (e.g. are you having difficulty drawing lines on PictureBoxes?) and eliminates other unrelated code (e.g. anything to do with signals and modulators) from the question not only makes the question easier to understand and answer, it may well help you to work out the answer yourself. Or at least that's how it's worked out for me quite a few times.

Comment: I edited the textposting ,I tried to color the picture boxes and they are displayed, but not their content.

Comment: `pictureBox.CreateGraphics();` is NOT the correct way to draw on your PBs. You need to make a decision: (1) Draw into the Bitmap for each PB, or (2) Draw "on top" of the Bitmap for each PB using the supplied `e.Graphics` in the `Paint()` event of each PB. The latter method would be more desirable if the waveform is going to change a lot and should be displayed over something that is static (not changing) below it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your program with an override Paint method for each PictureBox like this

```cs
   public partial class ModulationDemodulationExample : Form
    {
        // Declare controls and variables
        private const int SignalLength = 100;
        private PictureBox carrierSignalBox = new PictureBox();
        private PictureBox modulatorSignalBox = new PictureBox();
        private PictureBox modulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox();
        private PictureBox demodulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox();
        private double[] carrierSignal = new double[SignalLength];
        private double[] modulatorSignal = new double[SignalLength];
        private double[] modulatedSignal = new double[SignalLength];
        private double[] demodulatedSignal = new double[SignalLength];
        private double carrierFrequency = 2.0;
        public ModulationDemodulationExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Initialize form and controls
            Text = "Modulation and Demodulation Simulator";
            Size = new Size(800, 600);
            PictureBox carrierSignalBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Location = new Point(10, 10),
                Size = new Size(360, 180),
                Visible = true,
                Name = "Carrier Signal"
            };
            carrierSignalBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(carrierSignalBox_Paint);
            PictureBox modulatorSignalBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Location = new Point(10, 200),
                Size = new Size(360, 180),
                Visible = true,
                Name = "Modulator Signal"
            };
            modulatorSignalBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(modulatorSignalBox_Paint);
            PictureBox modulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Location = new Point(400, 10),
                Size = new Size(360, 180),
                Visible = true,
                Name = "Modulated Signal"
            };
            modulatedSignalBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(modulatedSignalBox_Paint);
            PictureBox demodulatedSignalBox = new PictureBox()
            {
                Location = new Point(400, 200),
                Size = new Size(360, 180),
                Visible = true,
                Name = "Demodulated Signal"
            };
            demodulatedSignalBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(demodulatedSignalBox_Paint);
            Controls.Add(carrierSignalBox);
            Controls.Add(modulatorSignalBox);
            Controls.Add(modulatedSignalBox);
            Controls.Add(demodulatedSignalBox);

            GenerateSignal();
        }
        
        private void GenerateSignal()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SignalLength; i++)
            {
                carrierSignal[i] = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * carrierFrequency * i);
                modulatorSignal[i] = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i);
                modulatedSignal[i] = carrierSignal[i] * modulatorSignal[i];
                demodulatedSignal[i] = modulatedSignal[i] * carrierSignal[i];
            }
        }

        private void carrierSignalBox_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawSignal(e.Graphics, carrierSignalBox, carrierSignal, Color.Blue);
        }
        private void modulatorSignalBox_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawSignal(e.Graphics, modulatorSignalBox, modulatorSignal, Color.Red);
        }
        private void modulatedSignalBox_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawSignal(e.Graphics, modulatedSignalBox, modulatedSignal, Color.Green);
        }
        private void demodulatedSignalBox_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawSignal(e.Graphics, demodulatedSignalBox, demodulatedSignal, Color.Black);
        }

        void DrawSignal(Graphics graphics, PictureBox pictureBox, double[] signal, Color color)
        {
            // Get the graphics object for the PictureBox
            //var graphics = pictureBox.CreateGraphics();
            // Clear the PictureBox
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            // Set the pen color
            var pen = new Pen(color);
            // Scale the signal's values to the size of the PictureBox
            var yScale = (double)pictureBox.Height / 2.0;
            var xScale = (double)pictureBox.Width / (double)signal.Length;
            // Draw the signal
            for (int i = 0; i < signal.Length - 1; i++)

            {
                var x1 = (int)(i * xScale);
                var y1 = (int)(yScale + (signal[i] * yScale));
                var x2 = (int)((i + 1) * xScale);
                var y2 = (int)(yScale + (signal[i + 1] * yScale));
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

When you want to redraw the PictureBox, just call the Invalidate method and the Paint event is automatically called. Example:

```cs
carrierSignalBox.Invalidate()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: how can I modify this code to get the spec waveformsifice modulation and demodulation in amplitude of an analog signal?@piferrari